# How to show an element for a desired screen size using bootstrap 4.1.1?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to show a button when screen size less is than 768 only. I am using latest version of `bootstrap(4.1.1)`. From a straightforward reference(https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/ ) I tried as follows:

```
  <button type="button" id="leftSidebarCollapse" class="navbar-btn  hidden-md-down">
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                    </button>
```

According to bootstrap 4, this button should be visible when screen size less is than 768 only. But it is not working as expected. It kill my day. Whats wrong is going on my code? Any idea?

Comment: Check the current docs, alpha is outdated: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/#hiding-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use bootstrap `d-sm-block` `d-md-none` classes for Visible only less than small screen.

```
<button type="button" id="leftSidebarCollapse" class="navbar-btn d-sm-block d-md-none">
 <span></span>
 <span></span>
 <span></span>
</button>
```

Please check here bootstrap [Display property](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/)